# Angular equivalent to Backbone collection.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Backbone has great methods for extracting and updating individual models (single datasets) which are part of a collection (array of objects).

I'm just learning Angular at the moment, and am being blown away by the binding, filtering and templating (much prefer to underscore). It makes light work of many tasks.

I'm struggling though, to find a simple way to pull a single object out of an array of objects. From what I've read on-line, my options are to use a filter on ng-repeat (which seems a bit odd as I'm not "repeating" anything, or to pull in jquery and use $.grep. Another way might be to build my own filter or to write something in raw javascript.

Which way would you use to pull a single object out of an array? Bear in mind that in Backbone, each object in a collection has a unique 'id' property, and I'm using the same paradigm with my business data in Angular. I'd rather not pull in jquery or underscore just to do that.

Apologies if an Angular method exists - I find the documentation a bit tricky to navigate. If it does, then please give an example of it in use. Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "pull a single object out of an array"? Are you after finding a certain object in array? If so, based on which criteria? A reference? Or some property values?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource In backbone every model in a collection has an id. I'm using the same paradigm with Angular. So each object in the array has an id property with a unique value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Backbone, `collection.findWhere` just delegates to Underscore's `find` method, which is really straightforward - it just loops through the collection until it hits an element that matches the predicate.

I'd just write a helper function to do that. For example:

```
function find(array, attrs) {
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    for (var key in attrs) {
      if (array[i][key] !== attrs[key]) {
        break;
      }
      return array[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

And use it like:

```
findFirst(items, {id: 3});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah pretty straightforward.  I guess Angular isn't designed with collection vs model in mind. As far as business data is concerned, it seems pretty collection oriented with many functions to manipulate the view of the collection, but nothing to extract or specifically manage an individual object in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a go w/ [Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs) -- it's pretty much my favorite thing ever and our team uses it extensively in Sails/Waterline and our client projects.  In particular, check out [`_.find()`](http://lodash.com/docs#find).

---

#### Common Usage

`var fluffyTheCat = _.find(cats, { name: 'fluffy' });`

---

#### Example

```
// assuming you've got "$scope.cats"

// you can do nice criteria-based lookups on a per-attribute basis:
_.find($scope.cats, { name: 'fluffy' });

// or do something lower-level:
// (return true to declare a match, false to keep going)
_.find($scope.cats, function (cat) {
  return cat.name.match(/^fluffy/i);
});
```

---

#### Docs

*from [http://lodash.com/docs#find:](http://lodash.com/docs#find%3a_)*

`_.find(collection, [callback=identity], [thisArg])`

Iterates over elements of a collection, returning the first element that the callback returns truey for. The callback is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments; (value, index|key, collection).

If a property name is provided for callback the created "_.pluck" style callback will return the property value of the given element.

If an object is provided for callback the created "_.where" style callback will return true for elements that have the properties of the given object, else false.

---

> Also see [`_.where()`](http://lodash.com/docs#where), which returns an array of matches instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't need to loop through each property in the object, ie I know I am only matching against the id property, I came up with this function which sits in my controller. It's called if I pass $routeParams.item to the controller. $routeParams.item specifies the 'id' of the object I want to get hold of. I apply the return value to the $scope.dataIs property, meaning I can now bind to it.

```
$scope.getDataIs = function(item){
    var dataIs;

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.data[i]['id'] == item) {
            dataIs = $scope.data[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return dataIs;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you could just replace that with a one liner if you used underscore's or lodash's `.find()`.